bad .npmignore file with ng build and angular library
I have created an angular 18 application with some libraries like this:
ng new myproj
cd myproj
ng generate library libone
ng generate library libtwo

I have created myproj/projects/libone/.npmignore and added some files that I don't want to be packaged, say 'alpha', 'beta', and 'gamma'. Then I add .npmignore to the assets section of my ng-package.json in the root of myproj/projects/libone.  When I am in myproj/projects/libone and run ng build ng builds my project into myproj/dist/libone.
So far so good, exactly as expected.  Except that when I look at myproj/dist/libone/.npmignore all I see is:
# Nested package.json's are only needed for development.
**/package.json

What I expect to see is:
alpha
beta
gamma

The exact contents of the .npmignore file that I created. In theory, the assets section of ng-package.json should copy static files from my library into the dist folder when I run ng build, and it does. Except for .npmignore.  When I cd into libtwo and build it, a new .npmignore file is created with just that same default text.
Is there any way around this so I can get my .npmignore settings into the dist for that package?
